# SVG in JSX image source tag does not work in production

Tags: reactjs, svg, jsx, create-react-app

I am trying to display an svg image with a JSX image tag like so:

```
import Logo from '../assets/img/icons/logo.svg'

... //component definition
render () {
  return (
    <img src={Logo} />
  )
}
```

This works perfectly when running the app locally with `npm start`.

But in the hosted version all svg images are not displayed.

*Using the same browser*

Comment: Are the svgs served statically? Then you'd need to use the correct path

Comment: Yes, they are served statically. The path is definitely working.

Comment: wrong mime type?

Comment: I don't think so, having the app hosted locally the image displays without any problems. Only when uploaded to an ftp server, the image does not get rendered.
Maybe it's something with the build version?

Comment: Nothing you've said is indicative of the mime-type being correct.

Comment: True, now I've checked: the MIME type is indeed false. It's ```text/plain```.

Comment: Do you know how to fix that? @RobertLongson

Comment: Depends on how you're hosting the image and you haven't explained that.

Comment: Well it's statically in a public folder within my app.